# Firefox/Chrome extension - block from new-tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing an [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) for Firefox and Chrome, which specifically targets the context-menu on textboxes (both single-line and multi-line)... and manipulates the value in the element.

To achieve this I'm creating new [context menu items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items) with `contexts` set to `editable`, and it's generally working as I want.

Due to permissions, I'm unable to manipulate the contents of the search textbox on the new-tab page of either Firefox or Chrome (I don't have a problem with this) and get the following error on Firefox when attempting to `executeScript` on the tab...

> Error: Missing host permission for the tab

However, what I can't figure out is how to stop the context menu items from appearing if the user right-clicks on a textbox on the new-tab page.  There isn't a [contextType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/ContextType) that would allow me to target that tab.

Is there any way to block the context menus on the new-tab page?

Comment: Use `documentUrlPatterns` when registering the menu.

Comment: Great - thanks @wOxxOm - that's what I needed. Although it's a pity that you can't exclude URL's, I've added `documentUrlPatterns: ["*://*/*","file:///*/*"]` and it appears to be doing what I need.  If you create an answer, I'll gladly upvote/mark.  Otherwise I'll add my own answer... let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for their comment which pointed me in the correct direction...

> Use `documentUrlPatterns` when registering the menu

As a result I have used the `documentUrlPatterns` property of the [`menus.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create) method, and it's working as I need it...

```
let validUrlPatterns = ["*://*/*", "file:///*/*"];

menus.create({
  ...
  documentUrlPatterns: validUrlPatterns,
  contexts: ["editable"]
});
```

In this case, I have two items - the first will match normal websites (http://, https://) and the second will match local files for testing (file:///)

For more information on match patterns, see [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)